# Solarized Monitor Color (ICC) profile

Tags: display, color-profiles, icc, solarized

Recently I used some [solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) color palettes in some of the text editors. I found this site from `SU`.
It's really amazing!!!

I'm curious if there is any Color (ICC) profile, like this for my desktop display monitor ( supported by it's driver)?
Or , is there any tool that can help me create own ICC color profiles, like this and use them with [Windows Color Control Panel Applet](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12714#overview) ?

Comment: I think you're confusing [color palettes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_palette) with [color profiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_profile) which do/are completely different things. `Solarized` is a color palette, not a profile.

Comment: @martineau: I did that 'Edit'...thanks. But ....., my thought is :  ICC profiles are not gonna be app-specific , requiring a color palette for each app. Please , correct me , if I'm wrong.

Comment: Color profiles are hardware specific. They're typically used to produce or retrieve true colors to for from a device. The solarized color palette is just a set of colors that can be used on various hardware devices by various software applications (most typically, text editors and terminal/console applications. Even if there's a tool out there to create your own ICC profile, it would not help you make some application start using the "solarized' palette of colors. How you do that, depends on application. Many text editors have settings that allow you to pick the colors you want it to use.